# Does Java Check cRLSign KeyUsage bit for CRL Issuing Certificates?

Tags: java, certificate, certificate-revocation

I'm using Java implementation for revocation checking using CRL which is like the following code (I tailored the code to be short and clear)

```
    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
    CertPathBuilder cpb = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX");
    PKIXRevocationChecker rc = (PKIXRevocationChecker)cpb.getRevocationChecker();

    rc.setOptions(EnumSet.of(
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.PREFER_CRLS,
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.ONLY_END_ENTITY,
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.NO_FALLBACK,
            PKIXRevocationChecker.Option.SOFT_FAIL)); 

    PKIXBuilderParameters pkixParams = 
            new PKIXBuilderParameters(getTrustStore(), new X509CertSelector());
    pkixParams.setRevocationEnabled(false);
    pkixParams.addCertPathChecker(rc);
    tmf.init(new CertPathTrustManagerParameters(pkixParams));

    SSLContext contect = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    context.init(null, getTrustManagers(), null);
    defaultFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
```

The above code is in the constructor of a custom SSLSocketFactory, and there is a custom TrustManager (returned by getTrustManagers()) which overrides checkServerTrusted() to perform a few certificate checks and executes default checkServerTrusted() at the end.
Everything works fine except that I need that validation of CRL to be failed when it is signed by a CA that does not have the cRLsign key usage
bit set, but it doesn't.

I know that this is a requirement by RFC3280, and somewhere on the web I read that Java implementation is compliant with the RFC and I even saw the methods in the Java base code to do that, But it seems it does not come into play when I run the application.

I did all the revocation checking with a custom code to achieve that but I think Java implementation is way more complete that my custom code and I strongly prefer to use Java implementation.

Any solution?